# What size of the picture will be sent through Instagram API?

Tags: instagram

What size of the picture will be sent through Instagram API? How does Instagram API decide to use which size of three (standard_resolution, thumbnail, low_resolution)?

Answer (score 0):

thumbnail = 150 px width, 150 px height

low_resolution = 320 px width, maintains aspect ratio or original for height

standard_resolution = 640 px width, maintains aspect ratio or original for height